# Json is not extracted to Java POJO object

Tags: java, gson, rest-assured

I'm using rest-assured with Gson for testing when getting a response from the BE service I'm creating a POJO object that deserializes the JSON and creates and object, but for some reason all object fields are null, FYI I'm using the same practice at another API calls and it works, but in this case, it's not.

```
{
    "allLanguages": [
        "English"
    ],
    "Messages": [
        {
            "Messages": null
        }
    ],
    "Content": [
        {
            "Subject": "EmailWithDOCAttachmentJCBKMJJ Test Email with docx attachment"
        },
        {
            "Content": "An email includes Docx file as an attachment"
        },
        {
            "Content Html": "<html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:w=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\"><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)\"><style><!--/* Font Definitions */@font-face{font-family:\"Cambria Math\";panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}@font-face{font-family:Calibri;panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}/* Style Definitions */p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal{margin:0cm;font-size:11.0pt;font-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;}span.EmailStyle17{mso-style-type:personal-compose;font-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;color:windowtext;}.MsoChpDefault{mso-style-type:export-only;font-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;}@page WordSection1{size:612.0pt 792.0pt;margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;}div.WordSection1{page:WordSection1;}--></style></head><body lang=\"en-IL\" link=\"#0563C1\" vlink=\"#954F72\" style=\"word-wrap:break-word\"><div class=\"WordSection1\"><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span lang=\"EN-US\">An email includes Docx file as an attachment<o:p></o:p></span></p></div></body></html>"
        },
        {
            "Record Date": "2023-01-30 12:27:53.000"
        }
    ],
    "Generic": [
        {
            "Date": "2023-01-30 12:27:53.000"
        },
        {
            "Date Added": "2023-01-30 10:30:51.146"
        },
        {
            "Date Time Created": "2023-01-30 12:27:53.000"
        },
        {
            "Date Time Received": "2023-01-30 10:27:58.090"
        },
        {
            "Index Name": "dr_smtpemail_2023.01.01_999"
        },
        {
            "Ecomm Id": "6BF42EAC97D5C20A071D34AB7BCE7B8C"
        },
        {
            "archive Ids": "[2]"
        },
        {
            
        },
        {
            
        },
        {
            "Record Date": "2023-01-30 12:27:53.000"
        },
        {
            "Ecomm Type": "E-Mail"
        },
        {
            "Platform Name": "SMTPEmail"
        },
        {
            
        },
        {
            "Retention date": "2023-07-31 12:27:53.000"
        },
        {
            "archiveRoot": "E-Mail/SMTPEmail/2023/01/30"
        },
        {
            "platformDisplayName": "SMTP Email"
        }
    ],
    "Product": [
        {
            "Product": [
                
            ]
        }
    ],
    "transcribedMessages": [
        {
            "transcribedMessages": null
        }
    ],
    "Participants": [
        {
            "Participants": [
                {
                    "Participant Account Bsk Country": null,
                    "Participant Is Surveillance Data": null,
                    "Participant Emp Global ID": null,
                    "Participant JOB ID": null,
                    "Participant Account Name": null,
                    "Participant AIM": null,
                    "Participant External Company": null,
                    "Participant Parent Group Display": null,
                    "Participant Type": "unknown",
                    "Participant LEV5": null,
                    "Participant First Name": null,
                    "Participant LEV4": null,
                    "Participant LEV6": null,
                    "Participant YJ": null,
                    "Participant Is Record Keeping": null,
                    "Participant Email": "monitor@ggg.com",
                    "Participant Unique Id": "monitor@ggg.com",
                    "Participant Manager Name": null,
                    "Participant Skype": null,
                    "Participant Bank Department": null,
                    "Participant Department Display": null,
                    "Participant Business Unit": null,
                    "Participant Division": null,
                    "Participant City": null,
                    "Participant Account Manager": null,
                    "Participant Department": null,
                    "Participant Name For Viewer": null,
                    "Participant Emp Sub Unit": null,
                    "Participant Job Description": null,
                    "Participant TCCID": null,
                    "Nationality Code": null,
                    "Participant Name": null,
                    "Participant Org Sub Unit": null,
                    "Participant Yahoo": null,
                    "Participant Id": null,
                    "Participant Display Name": null,
                    "Participant Region": null,
                    "Participant Trader ID": null,
                    "Participant Parent Group": null,
                    "Participant Manager ID": null,
                    "Participant Org Unit Name": null,
                    "Participant Country Code": null,
                    "Participant CLI": null,
                    "Participant Is Internal": "false",
                    "Participant Employee Status": null,
                    "Participant Last Name": null,
                    "Participant Delivery Type": null,
                    "Participant Nationality Code": null,
                    "Participant IMID": null,
                    "Participant SSN": null,
                    "Participant Account Number": null,
                    "Participant Secondary Email": null,
                    "Participant Role Type Name": null
                },
                {
                    "Participant Account Bsk Country": null,
                    "Participant Is Surveillance Data": "true",
                    "Participant Emp Global ID": "employeeIdGlobal-Adele",
                    "Participant JOB ID": "jobIdAdele",
                    "Participant Account Name": null,
                    "Participant AIM": null,
                    "Participant External Company": null,
                    "Participant Parent Group Display": "monitored group",
                    "Participant Type": "customer",
                    "Participant LEV5": "lev5-Adele",
                    "Participant First Name": "Adele",
                    "Participant LEV4": "lev4-Adele",
                    "Participant LEV6": "lev6-Adele",
                    "Participant YJ": null,
                    "Participant Is Record Keeping": "false",
                    "Participant Email": "adelev@ggg.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "Participant Unique Id": "Z778714Adele",
                    "Participant Manager Name": "manager-for Adele",
                    "Participant Skype": null,
                    "Participant Bank Department": null,
                    "Participant Department Display": "monitored group",
                    "Participant Business Unit": "businessUnit-Adele",
                    "Participant Division": "division-Adele",
                    "Participant City": "City-Adele",
                    "Participant Account Manager": null,
                    "Participant Department": "monitored_system_group",
                    "Participant Name For Viewer": null,
                    "Participant Emp Sub Unit": "division-Adele",
                    "Participant Job Description": "jobDescription-Adele",
                    "Participant TCCID": null,
                    "Nationality Code": "nationalityCode-Adele",
                    "Participant Name": "Adele Vance",
                    "Participant Org Sub Unit": "organizationalUnit-Adele",
                    "Participant Yahoo": null,
                    "Participant Id": "Z778714Adele",
                    "Participant Display Name": null,
                    "Participant Region": "AM",
                    "Participant Trader ID": null,
                    "Participant Parent Group": "monitored_system_group",
                    "Participant Manager ID": "11005328",
                    "Participant Org Unit Name": "orgUnitId-Adele",
                    "Participant Country Code": null,
                    "Participant CLI": null,
                    "Participant Is Internal": "true",
                    "Participant Employee Status": null,
                    "Participant Last Name": "Vance",
                    "Participant Delivery Type": null,
                    "Participant Nationality Code": "nationalityCode-Adele",
                    "Participant IMID": null,
                    "Participant SSN": null,
                    "Participant Account Number": null,
                    "Participant Secondary Email": null,
                    "Participant Role Type Name": null
                },
                {
                    "Participant Account Bsk Country": null,
                    "Participant Is Surveillance Data": "true",
                    "Participant Emp Global ID": "employeeIdGlobal-Alex",
                    "Participant JOB ID": "jobIdAlex",
                    "Participant Account Name": null,
                    "Participant AIM": null,
                    "Participant External Company": null,
                    "Participant Parent Group Display": "monitored group",
                    "Participant Type": "advisor",
                    "Participant LEV5": "lev5-Alex",
                    "Participant First Name": "Alex",
                    "Participant LEV4": "lev4-Alex",
                    "Participant LEV6": "lev6-Alex",
                    "Participant YJ": null,
                    "Participant Is Record Keeping": "false",
                    "Participant Email": "alexw@gggg.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "Participant Unique Id": "N306800Alex",
                    "Participant Manager Name": "manager-for Alex",
                    "Participant Skype": null,
                    "Participant Bank Department": null,
                    "Participant Department Display": "ggg monitored group",
                    "Participant Business Unit": "businessUnit-Alex",
                    "Participant Division": "division-Alex",
                    "Participant City": "City-Alex",
                    "Participant Account Manager": null,
                    "Participant Department": "monitored_system_group",
                    "Participant Name For Viewer": null,
                    "Participant Emp Sub Unit": "division-Alex",
                    "Participant Job Description": "jobDescription-Alex",
                    "Participant TCCID": null,
                    "Nationality Code": "nationalityCode-Alex",
                    "Participant Name": "Alex W",
                    "Participant Org Sub Unit": "organizationalUnit-Alex",
                    "Participant Yahoo": null,
                    "Participant Id": "N306800Alex",
                    "Participant Display Name": null,
                    "Participant Region": "WB",
                    "Participant Trader ID": null,
                    "Participant Parent Group": "monitored_system_group",
                    "Participant Manager ID": "53002941",
                    "Participant Org Unit Name": "orgUnitId-Alex",
                    "Participant Country Code": null,
                    "Participant CLI": null,
                    "Participant Is Internal": "true",
                    "Participant Employee Status": null,
                    "Participant Last Name": "W",
                    "Participant Delivery Type": null,
                    "Participant Nationality Code": "nationalityCode-Alex",
                    "Participant IMID": null,
                    "Participant SSN": null,
                    "Participant Account Number": null,
                    "Participant Secondary Email": null,
                    "Participant Role Type Name": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Participants Count": "3"
        }
    ],
    "Information": [
        {
            
        },
        {
            "Languages": null
        },
        {
            "Legal hold": "false"
        },
        {
            
        },
        {
            "Date Received": "2023-01-30 10:27:58.090"
        },
        {
            "Date sent": "2023-01-30 12:27:53.000"
        },
        {
            "Date Created": "2023-01-30 12:27:53.000"
        },
        {
            "Retention Date": "2023-07-31 12:27:53.000"
        },
        {
            "Ecomm Date": "2023-01-30 12:27:53.000"
        },
        {
            
        },
        {
            
        },
        {
            
        },
        {
            
        },
        {
            
        },
        {
            "Message Id": "<643565394.0.1675074473937.JavaMail.alitaha@ip-192-168-31-20.eu-west-1.compute.internal>"
        },
        {
            
        },
        {
            
        },
        {
            
        },
        {
            
        },
        {
            
        },
        {
            "Unique ID": "6BF42EAC97D5C20A071D34AB7BCE7B8C"
        }
    ],
    "Attachments": [
        {
            "Attachments": [
                {
                    "parent": null,
                    "isPasswordProtected": "false",
                    "sha256": "60984071781d33399dd72ebbd3e06b9e481ec4cd1d89ef38218fc1653732df",
                    "fileSize": "6122",
                    "archiveFilename": "/7_2023-01-30_10-30-29.444/Tasks/27/attachments/488E00680FF11FFED143409A9F7575B5-Automationtest.docx",
                    "fileContent": "Automation test"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "primaryLanguage": "English"
}
```

here are the relevant POJOS files:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class OriginalDTO {

    @SerializedName("Attachments")
    private List<Attachment> attachments;
    @SerializedName("BccRecipients")
    private List<BccRecipient> bccRecipients;
    @SerializedName("CcRecipients")
    private List<CcRecipient> ccRecipients;
    @SerializedName("Content")
    private List<Content> content;
    @SerializedName("FromRecipients")
    private List<FromRecipient> fromRecipients;
    @SerializedName("Generic")
    private List<Generic> generic;
    @SerializedName("Information")
    private List<Information> information;
    @SerializedName("Messages")
    private List<Message> messages;
    @SerializedName("Participants")
    private List<Participant> participants;
    @SerializedName("Product")
    private List<Product> product;
    @SerializedName("ToRecipients")
    private List<ToRecipient> toRecipients;
    @SerializedName("transcribedMessages")
    private List<TranscribedMessage> transcribedMessages;

}




@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class OriginalDTO {

    @SerializedName("Attachments")
    private List<Attachment> attachments;
    @SerializedName("BccRecipients")
    private List<BccRecipient> bccRecipients;
    @SerializedName("CcRecipients")
    private List<CcRecipient> ccRecipients;
    @SerializedName("Content")
    private List<Content> content;
    @SerializedName("FromRecipients")
    private List<FromRecipient> fromRecipients;
    @SerializedName("Generic")
    private List<Generic> generic;
    @SerializedName("Information")
    private List<Information> information;
    @SerializedName("Messages")
    private List<Message> messages;
    @SerializedName("Participants")
    private List<Participant> participants;
    @SerializedName("Product")
    private List<Product> product;
    @SerializedName("ToRecipients")
    private List<ToRecipient> toRecipients;
    @SerializedName("transcribedMessages")
    private List<TranscribedMessage> transcribedMessages;

}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Attachment {

    @SerializedName("archiveFilename")
    private String archiveFilename;
    @SerializedName("Attachments")
    private List<Attachment> attachments;
    @SerializedName("fileContent")
    private String fileContent;
    @SerializedName("fileSize")
    private String fileSize;
    @SerializedName("isPasswordProtected")
    private String isPasswordProtected;
    @SerializedName("parent")
    private String parent;
    @SerializedName("sha256")
    private String sha256;

}
```

And do on, in order to create the java object I'm using this code:

```
OriginalDTO original = response.then().statusCode(200).extract().as(OriginalDTO.class);
```

but for some reason all OriginalDTO fields values are null.
what I need to fix in this code

Comment: You are ignoring some levels. For example, your JSon doesn't have a list of `Attachment`. It has a list of objects with the attribute `Attachments`, each of which is a list of `Attachment`. It's a really horrible JSON. Do you have any control of it?

Comment: actually, I do not have control over the JSON,  and I need to use it as it, also I implemented all JSON levels in the same way, but did not add to them here because it is a huge chunk of code, my goal is to prescribe the issue, do you have any solution to this,

Comment: So you need to add those levels to your POJO. Look at the JSON carefully, and see what is actually in it, and if there are intermediate levels create objects for them.

Comment: The Participants, Generic, Content json have field names with spaces - very unusual. Can you please add the all the class definitions to your post and I will try to debug.

Comment: Please include the complete code which sets up REST Assured, my suspicion is that it is not properly set up to use Gson, and therefore ignores Gson's `@SerializedName` annotations. Also note that the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotations you are using come from Jackson and therefore have no effect on Gson.

Answer (score 0):

I handled this with work around using

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
OriginalDTO original = gson.fromJson(response.body().asString(), OriginalDTO.class);
```

instead of

`OriginalDTO original =response.then().statusCode(200).extract().as(OriginalDTO.cl`ass)